# Unificar este código css para reutilizar clases

Tags: html, css, css3, scss, selectores-css

tengo este código CSS que me funciona, pero he intentado unificarlo y no me funciona.

```
#menu-header-neumaticos > a > span.menu-mobil {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color:white;
}

#menu-header-coches > a > span.menu-mobil {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color:white;
}
```

Lo he unificado de esta forma, he probado estas dos formas

```
#menu-header-neumaticos,#menu-header-coches > a > **span.menu-mobil** {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color:white;
}
```

O bien de esta forma

```
#menu-header-neumaticos,#menu-header-coches > a > **span**{
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color:white;
}
```

Y no me funciona, no me aplica el css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien lo que pretendes hacer con esos asteriscos. Quizás se utilicen en **SCSS**, con el cual no estoy familiarizado. Pero lo que pretendes se puede hacer con **CSS** directamente. Lo único que tienes que hacer es plasmar ambos selectores separados por una coma para que se le apliquen las reglas a los dos.

```css
#menu-header-neumaticos > a > span.menu-mobil, 
#menu-header-coches > a > span.menu-mobil {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-header-neumaticos">
  <a href="#"><span class="menu-mobil">Neumáticos</span></a>
</div>

<div id="menu-header-coches">
  <a href="#"><span class="menu-mobil">Coches</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, he aplicado tu solución.

Answer (score 2):

En `SASS` podrías hacer:

#### Opción 1

```
#menu-header-neumaticos,
#menu-header-coches {
    > a > span.menu-mobil {
        border-bottom: none !important;
        color:white;
    }
}
```

#### Opción 2 (*usando `@extend`*)

```
#menu-header-neumaticos > a > span.menu-mobil {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color:red;
}

#menu-header-coches {
  @extend #menu-header-neumaticos
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.